# PHP strtotime function assessment

Tags: php, strtotime

I'm using strtotime function for a minor project, and it's a really powerful tool but I just need some help getting to the insides of it.

Is there any way to catch when it automatically evaluates a given date?
For example when you input strtotime("2/30/2006") it will return a timestamp for 3/2/2006. 
Or if you put any date before 1970, it will return a timestamp for 1/1/1970.

For these inputs, the strtotime function must be doing something to assess these strings, and I was wondering if there was any way to catch these triggers.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but valid date formats are listed [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) if that's helpful.

Comment: I am not sure what are you referring to as *triggers* or *catching the triggers*.

Answer (score 1):

The strtotime() function parses an English textual datetime into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Note: If the year is specified in a two-digit format, values between 0-69 are mapped to 2000-2069 and values between 70-100 are mapped to 1970-2000.

Note: Be aware of dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats; if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed. If the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. To avoid potential errors, you should YYYY-MM-DD dates or date_create_from_format() when possible.

Date has definite formats to be entered :

```
d - The day of the month (from 01 to 31)D - A textual representation of a day (three letters)j - The day of the month without leading zeros (1 to 31)l (lowercase 'L') - A full textual representation of a dayN - The ISO-8601 numeric representation of a day (1 for Monday, 7 for Sunday)S - The English ordinal suffix for the day of the month (2 characters st, nd, rd or th. Works well with j)w - A numeric representation of the day (0 for Sunday, 6 for Saturday)z - The day of the year (from 0 through 365)W - The ISO-8601 week number of year (weeks starting on Monday)F - A full textual representation of a month (January through December)m - A numeric representation of a month (from 01 to 12)M - A short textual representation of a month (three letters)n - A numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros (1 to 12)t - The number of days in the given monthL - Whether it's a leap year (1 if it is a leap year, 0 otherwise)o - The ISO-8601 year numberY - A four digit representation of a yeary - A two digit representation of a yeara - Lowercase am or pmA - Uppercase AM or PMB - Swatch Internet time (000 to 999)g - 12-hour format of an hour (1 to 12)G - 24-hour format of an hour (0 to 23)h - 12-hour format of an hour (01 to 12)H - 24-hour format of an hour (00 to 23)i - Minutes with leading zeros (00 to 59)s - Seconds, with leading zeros (00 to 59)u - Microseconds (added in PHP 5.2.2)e - The timezone identifier (Examples: UTC, GMT, Atlantic/Azores)I (capital i) - Whether the date is in daylights savings time (1 if Daylight Savings Time, 0 otherwise)O - Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours (Example: +0100)P - Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours:minutes (added in PHP 5.1.3)T - Timezone abbreviations (Examples: EST, MDT)Z - Timezone offset in seconds. The offset for timezones west of UTC is negative (-43200 to 50400)c - The ISO-8601 date (e.g. 2013-05-05T16:34:42+00:00)r - The RFC 2822 formatted date (e.g. Fri, 12 Apr 2013 12:01:05 +0200)U - The seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)
```

and the following predefined constants can also be used (available since PHP 5.1.0):

DATE_ATOM - Atom (example: 2013-04-12T15:52:01+00:00)DATE_COOKIE - HTTP Cookies (example: Friday, 12-Apr-13 15:52:01 UTC)DATE_ISO8601 - ISO-8601 (example: 2013-04-12T15:52:01+0000)DATE_RFC822 - RFC 822 (example: Fri, 12 Apr 13 15:52:01 +0000)DATE_RFC850 - RFC 850 (example: Friday, 12-Apr-13 15:52:01 UTC)DATE_RFC1036 - RFC 1036 (example: Fri, 12 Apr 13 15:52:01 +0000)DATE_RFC1123 - RFC 1123 (example: Fri, 12 Apr 2013 15:52:01 +0000)DATE_RFC2822 - RFC 2822 (Fri, 12 Apr 2013 15:52:01 +0000)DATE_RFC3339 - Same as DATE_ATOM (since PHP 5.1.3)DATE_RSS - RSS (Fri, 12 Aug 2013 15:52:01 +0000)DATE_W3C - World Wide Web Consortium (example: 2013-04-12T15:52:01+00:00)

Visit here for info 
[Php strtotime ()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp)